# Hold and Unhold call using pjsua2 Android

Tags: android, sip, voip, pjsip

I'm using pjsua2 with Android build version 2.2.1.
I can put a call on hold using:

```
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
    prm.setOptions(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UPDATE_CONTACT.swigValue());

    try {
        currentCall.setHold(prm)
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

To unhold call I tried this, but does not work:

```
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
    prm.setOptions(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD.swigValue());

    try {
        currentCall.reinvite(prm);
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Is that a bug of pjsua? How should I call the reinvite method?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Look my code:

```
public void holdCall() {
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

    try {
        currentCall.setHold(prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void unHoldCall() {
    CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam(true);

    prm.getOpt().setFlag(1);
    try {
        currentCall.reinvite(prm);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

According to [this issue](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/changeset/4780), it's necessary to set flag on `CallOpParam`.

The constant `PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD == 1`, but I couldn't use `PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD` directly.

I'm using Asterisk and it's working.

Comment: Hi, Can you please let me know how to play wav file to notify another user that call is on the hold.

Comment: Are you able to make hold on both sides? Cause when I am trying to hold the call from the calling side is ok, but from the receiving side it stops the call, sending disconnect.

Answer (score 3):

To unhold the call I need this in version 2.4.5:

```
CallOpParam prm = new CallOpParam();
CallSetting opt = prm.getOpt();
opt.setAudioCount(1);
opt.setVideoCount(0);
opt.setFlag(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD.swigValue());
call.reinvite(prm);
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another example:

```
public void setHold(boolean hold) {
    CallOpParam param = new CallOpParam();

    try {
        if (hold) {
            setHold(param);
        } else {
            CallSetting opt = param.getOpt();
            opt.setAudioCount(1);
            opt.setVideoCount(0);
            opt.setFlag(pjsua_call_flag.PJSUA_CALL_UNHOLD.swigValue());
            reinvite(param);
        }
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        String operation = hold ? "hold" : "unhold";
        Logger.error(LOG_TAG, "Error : ", exc);
    }
}
```

You can find [here](https://github.com/VoiSmart/pjsip-android/blob/master/sipservice/src/main/java/net/gotev/sipservice/SipCall.java) the full implementation.